# Table Partitioned by Timestamp Field

Tags: hadoop, hive

In order to generate some summary figures we are importing data periodically to Hive. We are currently using a CSV file format and its layout is as follows:

```
operation,item,timestamp,user,marketingkey
```

Currently we have a few queries that are performing grouping over date (yyyy-mm-dd) of timestamp field.

The files that are being imported are holding sometimes more days and I would like to store it in a partitioned way. Is there a way to do it with Hive, I have build the table based on the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE 
   partitionedTable (name string) 
PARTITIONED BY (time bigint) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

The data loading was done like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 
   '/home/spaeth/tmp/hadoop-billing-data/extracted/testData.csv' 
INTO TABLE partitionedTable PARTITION(time='2013-05-01');
```

But I would like that hive applies the partitioning in an automatic way based on a field that comes within the file that is being imported. For example:

```
login,1,1370793184,user1,none --> stored to partition 2013-06-09
login,2,1360793184,user1,none --> stored to partition 2013-02-13
login,1,1360571184,user2,none --> stored to partition 2013-02-11
buy,2,1360501184,user2,key1   --> stored to partition 2013-02-10
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for dynamic partitioning, and Hive supports dynamic partition inserts as detailed [in this article](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicPartitionInsert).

First, you need to create a temporary table where you will put your flat data with no partition at all. In your case this would be:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    flatTable (type string, id int, ts bigint, user string, key string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Then, you should load your flat data file into this directory:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH
    '/home/spaeth/tmp/hadoop-billing-data/extracted/testData.csv'
INTO TABLE flatTable;
```

At that point you can use the dynamic partition insert. A few things to keep in mind are that you'll need the following properties:

- `hive.exec.dynamic.partition` should be set to `true` because dynamic partition is disabled by default I believe.
- `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode` should be set to `nonstrict` because you have a single partition and strict mode enforces that you need one static partition.

So you can run the following query:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
FROM
    flatTable
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE
    partitionedTable
PARTITION(time)
SELECT
    user, from_unixtime(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS time
```

This should spawn 2 MapReduce jobs, and at the end you should see something along the lines of:

```
Loading data to table default.partitionedtable partition (time=null)
    Loading partition {time=2013-02-10}
    Loading partition {time=2013-02-11}
    Loading partition {time=2013-02-13}
    Loading partition {time=2013-06-09}
```

And to verify that your partitions are indeed here:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/partitionedTable/
Found 4 items
drwxr-xr-x   - username supergroup          0 2013-11-25 18:35 /user/hive/warehouse/partitionedTable/time=2013-02-10
drwxr-xr-x   - username supergroup          0 2013-11-25 18:35 /user/hive/warehouse/partitionedTable/time=2013-02-11
drwxr-xr-x   - username supergroup          0 2013-11-25 18:35 /user/hive/warehouse/partitionedTable/time=2013-02-13
drwxr-xr-x   - username supergroup          0 2013-11-25 18:35 /user/hive/warehouse/partitionedTable/time=2013-06-09
```

Please note that dynamic partitions are only supported since Hive 0.6, so if you have an older version this is probably not going to work.